# How to build a dynamic string from a List of Objects?

Tags: c#, list, stringbuilder

Lets say that I have a list of class called Filter

```
 public class Filter
    {
        [JsonProperty("field")]
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("operator")]
        public object Operator {get; set;}
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0} in ('{1}')", this.ColumnName, this.ColumnValue);
        }
     }
```

I need I could have a list of Filters where the column name could be the same.

So I could have an instance of ColumnName "LoanNumber" multiple times one for each instance of the class in the List. Each LoanNumber will have a completely different value. So I need to gather all of the values and put them under one single LoanNumber for an In clause string.

How can I loop through the list of filters and build a string that looks like this

```
string where = "LoanNum in (1234,456, 55676) and Dates in (01/01/2019, 01/02/2019)";
```

So far I am having trouble getting all of the data to look like above

```
 private string CreateWhereClause(List<Filter> filter)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
            foreach(var f in filter)
            {
                if (!sb.ToString().Contains(f.ColumnName))
                {
                    sb.Append(f.ToString() + " AND ");
                }else
                {
                    sb.Append(f.ToString() + " AND ");
                }
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 4);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

The problem with above is I get a string that looks like this
`LoanNum in (1234) and LoanNum in (3456) and Dates in (...) and Dates in (...)`,

Comment: Can you post those strings you're getting? because to me 
"LoanNum in (1234) and LoanNum in (3456) and Dates in (...) and Dates in (...)" 
is exactly what should be created. IS your intention to pair a LoanNum with a Dates?

Comment: Yea I posted them above.

Comment: updated my comment wiht another question ;-)

Comment: Is operator not used?

Comment: Why not have a collection of values per filter? So you only have one filter per column with a list of values to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. You could do

```
var list = new List<Filter>
{
    new Filter{ColumnName="LoanNum",ColumnValue="1234"},
    new Filter{ColumnName="Dates",ColumnValue="01/01/2019"},
    new Filter{ColumnName="LoanNum",ColumnValue="456"},
    new Filter{ColumnName="Dates",ColumnValue="01/02/2019"},
    new Filter{ColumnName="LoanNum",ColumnValue="55676"},
};


var subResult = list
    .GroupBy(filter => filter.ColumnName)
    .Select(group => string.Format("{0} in ({1})", group.Key,
        string.Join(",", group.Select(filter => filter.ColumnValue))));

var where = string.Join(" and ", subResult);
```

Output

```
LoanNum in (1234,456,55676) and Dates in (01/01/2019,01/02/2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `GroupBy` and `Select` is the best way to go, but in case you were wondering how to do it in a loop as you first started doing, one way would be to use a dictionary, where the `Key` is the `ColumnName`, and the `Value` is a comma-separated list of the associated `ColumnValue` strings:

```
private static string CreateWhereClause(List<Filter> filters)
{
    if (filters == null) return null;
    if (!filters.Any()) return string.Empty;

    var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        if (results.ContainsKey(filter.ColumnName))
        {
            results[filter.ColumnName] += $",'{filter.ColumnValue}'";
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(filter.ColumnName, $"'{filter.ColumnValue}'");
        }
    }

    return string.Join(" AND ", results.Select(result => 
        $"{result.Key} IN ({result.Value})"));
}
```

Putting it to use might look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var filters = new List<Filter>
    {
        new Filter {ColumnName = "LoanNum", ColumnValue = "1234"},
        new Filter {ColumnName = "Dates", ColumnValue = "01/01/2019"},
        new Filter {ColumnName = "LoanNum", ColumnValue = "456"},
        new Filter {ColumnName = "Dates", ColumnValue = "01/02/2019"},
        new Filter {ColumnName = "LoanNum", ColumnValue = "55676"},
    };

    var query = $"SELECT LOANS WHERE {CreateWhereClause(filters)}";

    Console.WriteLine(query);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]